# C: Passing an array as a parameter to the function results in garbage while sending a pointer works correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, debugging, function-pointers

So I have this function:

```
int fillPricesTable(double* flightsPrices,
                        int     n,
                        double* dollarRate) 
    {   
        int i = 0;
        while (*dollarRate <= 0) {
            scanf("%lf", dollarRate);
                if (*dollarRate <= 0) {
                errorDollar();
                }
        }
        while (scanf("%lf", flightsPrices+i)!=EOF) {
            if (*(flightsPrices+i) <= 0) {
                errorPrice(i - 1 / 6);
                return -1;
            }
                i++;
            }
        return (i / 6);

        }
```

If I change the pointer in the function definition to a 2D array this line:

```
"if (*(flightsPrices+i) <= 0)"
```

doesn't work.
I thought 2D arrays in function definition work like pointers to the array. So what's going on?

What I mean is if in the function definition I write an array instead of a pointer like this:

```
int fillPricesTable(double flightsPrices[][DEST], int n, double* dollarRate);
```

Then the function doesn't work.

I also get this warning from visual studio:

```
Non-float passed as argument '2' when float is required in call to 'scanf' Actual type: 'double [6]'.
```

Help

Comment: FWIW, `double[][] == double**`, not `double*`.

Comment: Regarding your warning, `double [6]` is the actual type but it's expecting the type `double*`. Example: `double d; scanf("%lf", &d);`

Comment: How do you define, initialise and pass what you pass to the function `fillPricesTable()`? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I understood the problem with the syntax but I still don't get how to get rid of the warning. 
How should I correctly write
scanf("%lf", flightsPrices+i) if flightsprices is 2d array?

Comment: Why do try to pass a 2D-array to a function handling only one dimension?

Comment: @JohnForkosh and @Mateen, `double[][]` is in no shape or form the same as `double **`

Comment: `void foo(double d[][]) {}` won't even compile.

Comment: If `flightPrices` is a 2D array, maybe you should use normal array indexing: `scanf("%lf", &flightsPrices[x][y]);`